# Поле name при создании внешнего ключа

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Не очень знаком с базами данных, впервые создаю БД на MySQL.
Использую Navicat и её модуль "model" для моделирования бд через схемки.
И мне не понятно, когда создаешь внешний ключ, за что отвечает поле name?
Оставить пустым его не получается.
Какую функцию оно выполняет?
Вопрос наверняка касается базы данных в целом, а не Navicat или mysql в частности.
Конкретно по примеру, то тут берется id для отношения "руководитель-подчиненный" (отдельно созданная таблица), в которой два внешних ключа. Оба ссылаются на id из таблицы "Сотрудники".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А посмотрите CREATE TABLE полученной таблицы - там и увидите, куда пихается введённое значение...

Comment: @Akina да дело в том, что никуда вроде бы не пихается... Вот [скриншот](http://joxi.ru/EA4b9GQFwaqRzm). Это автоматический запрос по выбранной таблице.

Comment: @Akina а нет, пихается. [Скриншот.](http://joxi.ru/52ae895S4vxyP2). Только я не понимаю, зачем. Как это используется?

Comment: Синтаксис допускает, а навикат - требует наличие имени констрейнта. Ну в общем имеет право.